# Find (if possible) conditions on a and b such that the system has no solution, one solution, and infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

x + by = -1

ax + 2y = 5

### So I made a matrix:

[1 -b | -1]

[1 a | 3]

=

[1 -b | -1]

[0 (a+b) | 3]

Here is where I'd figure to say: (a+b) must equal 3 for a solution to exist. I feel like I'm missing something.

(Don't give me the answer, the next step would be appreciated!)

Comment: Your guess is a little off. The last row is the equation $(a+b)y = 3$. So what do we need for a solution to exist?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Solving system of equations in two variable leads me to $x=\frac{2+5b}{ab-2}$ and $y=\frac{-(a+5)}{ab-2}$. Clearly for a solution to exist, $ab \neq 2 $.

Alternatively, by Cramer's Method, the determinant is 
\begin{equation}D=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & b\\
a & 2
\end{vmatrix} =2-ab
\end{equation}
for a solution to exist $D =0 \implies 2-ab \neq 0$. This gives $ab \neq 2$.

For infinitely many solutions, the following determinants must vanish
\begin{equation}D_x=
\begin{vmatrix}
-1 & b\\
5 & 2
\end{vmatrix} =0,D_y=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -1\\
a & 5
\end{vmatrix}=0
\end{equation}
solving above, we get $b=-2/5$ and $a=-5$.

For no solution, $D=0$ and either $D_x =0, D_y \neq0$ OR $D_x \neq 0, D_y =0$. This gives $(ab=2, b \neq -2/5, a=-5)$ OR ($ab=2,b = -2/5, a\neq-5 $).